# How to save a dataframe as csv to github repository python

Tags: python, dataframe, github

I have a dataframe named "domains". I want to save it as csv to my github project. How do I do that?

Many thanks!

Comment: [DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas to save the data frame as a csv file in the local folder that your GitHub repo is attached to;

```
domains.to_csv("path_to_local_git_folder/domains.csv")
```

More info about this function is on the [pandas website](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Then once you have your csv file locally, you can add, commit and push to GitHub just like you would a python script.